# Confused on Java Stream Results using peek and findAny

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm new to Java's Stream API, and I'm confused on the results of this case:

```
Stream<String> stream = Stream.of("A","B","C","D");
System.out.println(stream.peek(System.out::println).findAny().get());
```

This prints:

```
A
A
```

Why does it not print:

```
A
A
B
B
C
C
D
D
```

Comment: Even in the worst case, if I would have expected an incorrect output, it would have been rather `A B C D A` ...traversing all and still finding any(one). Not sure what made you think `A A B B ...` should be the result though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`findAny` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny()) doesn't find all the elements; it finds just one element.

> Returns an `Optional` describing some element of the stream, or an empty `Optional` if the stream is empty.
>
> This is a short-circuiting terminal operation.

The stream is not processed until a terminal method is called, in this case, `findAny`.  But the [`peek` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)) doesn't execute its action on an element until the element is consumed by the terminal action.

> In cases where the stream implementation is able to optimize away the production of some or all the elements (such as with short-circuiting operations like `findFirst`, or in the example described in `count()`), the action will not be invoked for those elements.

The `findAny` method is short-circuiting, so `peek`'s action will only be called for that element found by `findAny`.

That is why you only get two `A` values in the printout.  One is printed by the `peek` method, and you print the second, which is the value inside the `Optional` returned by `findAny`.